# Magento 1.x block data inheritance

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, collection

I would like to know how does Magento blocks pass data to its child blocks. Example:

```xml
<reference name="content">
    <block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml">
        <block type="page/html_pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
    </block>
</reference>
```

Here, if I take the block `product_list_toolbar_pager` out from `product_list_toolbar_pager` and create a block of type `page/html_pager` as a child block for the block `catalog.view`, it will not receive the data from the current collection I am visiting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not about data inheritance but about explicit setting the data to the child block.

Take a look at the method `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Toolbar::getPagerHtml()` and you will understand how that works.

The child block is loaded and all the data is set.

If you move the pager outside of the toolbar block you will need to set that missing data somehow in your code.